# Stream analytics Gzip compressed output creation using powershell is not working

Tags: powershell, azure-stream-analytics

Not able to create a azure stream analytics(ASA) compressed output using power shell. I was following the below sample which explains about how to create ASA output using power shell. In the "Configure input to the job" json sample, I changed the 
 **compression": {
            "type": "GZip"
        }**. but the change is not reflecting after the power shell deployment. I change the compression type to Gzip to manually in azure portal, however after running the power shell script again, the compression is reset to none. Has anyone tried to compress ASA output using power shell?

https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/////stream-analytics/stream-analytics-quick-create-powershell

Comment: Any update now? If it helps you, you could accept it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Stream Analytics supports [compression](http://Stream%20Analytics%20supports%20compression%20across%20all%20data%20stream%20input%20sources.%20Supported%20compression%20types%20are:%20None,%20GZip,%20and%20Deflate%20compression.) across all data stream **input** sources. Supported compression types are: `None`, `GZip`, and `Deflate` compression.

And it seems that it **not supports for gzip compression on Stream Analytics Output**. You could vote up your voice on this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270577-stream-analytics/suggestions/31847635-support-for-gzip-compression-on-stream-analytics-o) to promote this feature to be achieved.